# Using backticks or $() with xargs and sed or awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk, xargs

Assuming I want to change some filenames that end with `jpg.jpg` to end only with `.jpg` (in bash), and I want to do it by piping the output of `find` to `xargs`:

By using `sed`:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | xargs -I % mv -iv % $(echo % | sed 's/jpg.jpg/.jpg/g')
```

However, this does not replace `jpg.jpg` with `.jpg` in the destination file of `mv`.

By using `awk`:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | xargs -I % mv -iv % $(echo % | awk '{gsub(/jpg.jpg/,".jpg")}; 1')
```

This neither does any replacement. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this by writing a script that takes filenames and does the rename:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE
do
    mv $FILE `basename $FILE jpg.jpg`.jpg
done
```

That script is easily called via `xargs`.

If you want to smash it onto a single command line you can do it but it's usually not worth the trouble.

EDIT: If I had to do it on one command line I'd probably use a different trick without `xargs`:  Use `sed` to turn the output of `find` into a shell script:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)jpg\.jpg$/mv & \1.jpg/' | sh
```

The advantage of `xargs` being able to fork off fewer children is defeated by the need to run `mv` repeatedly anyway.  If you really need *that* advantage you need a solution like my first option but coded in something like `perl` which can execute multiple `rename()` calls without forking off any `mv`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Generally true, but I felt it would be confusing to dwell on those details when `xargs` is going to split filenames at spaces anyway.  If you take Ed's advice, use `... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the `rename` command available on your system, then the following command should work:

```
rename 's/(.*)jpg.jpg/$1.jpg/g' *jpg.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$(...)` is evaluated by bash before running xargs, so xargs just sees the output of that expression as it currently stands as the second argument to mv.

So it is equivalent to:

```
... | xargs -I % mv % %
```

Comment: What is the correct way to get around this (run sed on the original string, yet have the whole sed operation embedded in the middle of a command that uses the original, unsedded string? See my related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636184/using-sed-on-xarg-variable-isnt-working-inside-shell-expansion

Answer (score 2):

I would go with GNU parallel for this:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel mv {} {.}
```

`{}` is replaced by the input, `{.}` is replaced by the input minus last extension. Use `--dry-run` with parallel to see what will be done.

#### Edit - should handle file1jpg.jpg

Depending on your needs with regards to keeping case, this can be done with parameter expansion or with GNU sed:

Parameter expansion:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel v={}\; mv '{}' '${v/jpg.jpg/.jpg}'
```

With GNU sed:

```
find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel mv '{}' '$(echo {} | sed -r "s/jpg\\.(jpg)$/.\1/I")'
```

Comment: If I have eg. a file `file1jpg.jpg`, `find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel mv {} {.}` renames `file1jpg.jpg` to `file1jpg`. What I want is to rename `file1jpg.jpg` to `file1.jpg`, not `file1jpg`.

Comment: @nrz: It can still be done with parallel, just becomes more complicated. See edit.

Comment: The command using parameter expansion works, but the command using GNU `sed` fails with: `mv: missing destination file operand after `./file2jpg.jpg'` `Try `mv --help' for more information.`

Comment: @nrz: what commands is parallel trying to run? you can list them with `--dry-run`.

Comment: If there is a file `file1jpg.jpg`, `find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel --dry-run mv '{}' '$(<<< {} | sed -r "s/jpg\\.(jpg)$/.\1/I")'` prints the following: `mv ./file1jpg.jpg $(<<< ./file1jpg.jpg | sed -r "s/jpg\\.(jpg)$/.\1/I")` .

Comment: @nrz: I was testing it with zsh where the `<<<` wasn't causing any problems, with it seems `echo` is needed. Try it now.

Comment: In bash both `find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel v={}\; mv '{}' '${v/jpg.jpg/.jpg}'` and `find . -iname '*jpg.jpg' | parallel mv '{}' '$(echo {} | sed -r "s/jpg\\.(jpg)$/.\1/I")'` work as expected with `file1jpg.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `xargs` or `find`:

```
for i in *jpg.jpg; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/jpg.jpg$/.jpg/')"; done
```

And there's no real need for `sed` or `awk` either:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*jpg.jpg"); do mv "$i" "${i/%jpg.jpg/.jpg}"; done
```

Here's another way:

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg.jpg" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/%jpg.jpg/.jpg}' {} \;
```

Comment: The first line works properly, the second gives error `mv: cannot move  \`./myfilejpg.jpg' to \`./myfile.jpg/': Not a directory.` This can be fixed by changing `"${i/%jpg.jpg/.jpg/}"` to `"${i/%jpg.jpg/.jpg}"`. The third line seems to work with a similar fix.