# Using sed on xargs variable isn't working inside shell expansion

Tags: bash, sed, redis

I am attempting to do a batch key rename in Redis, using the shell to sed a replacement for each key name. (There doesn't seem to be a better way to do this in redis internally).

```
redis-cli -n 5 KEYS "*::staging::*"| xargs -I {} echo "RENAME {} $(echo {} | sed 's/staging/development/g')" 
# Then pipe this command into redis-cli when working
```

I am expecting an output like this:
`"RENAME redis::staging::key redis::development::key"`

Instead I just get this:
`"RENAME redis::staging::key redis::staging::key"`

The `echo {} $(echo {}| sed 's/old/new/')` is what is hanging me up... 
How does one properly achieve taking an `xargs` output and echo both the original and an edited version of that? `$(echo {} |sed)` should work, right? (If so, how can I do it correctly?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution with sed alone

sed, itself, is able to produce both the unmodified and the modified line:

```
$ echo "redis::staging::key" | sed 's/^/RENAME /; p; s/staging/development/g'
RENAME redis::staging::key
RENAME redis::development::key
```

In the above, sed first adds the RENAME string to the beginning of the line.  Then, the `p` command tells sed to print the line as it stands at that time (with "staging" still in it).  The next substitution puts in "development" and then that version is printed also.

**Update:**  Suppose we want the output on one line:

```
$ echo "redis::staging::key" | sed 's/.*/RENAME & &/; s/staging/development/2'
RENAME redis::staging::key redis::development::key
```

The first `s` command above adds RENAME to the beginning and then doubles the line.  The second replaces the second occurrence of staging with development.

#### Why didn't the xargs version do the substitution?

```
xargs -I {} echo "RENAME {} $(echo {} | sed 's/staging/development/g')"
```

Before xargs executes, bash processes the strings.  In particular, it sees `$(echo {} | sed 's/staging/development/g')` and it executes it ("command substitution") and gets the result `{}`.  So, when xargs is finally run, it sees the command:

```
xargs -I {} echo "RENAME {} {}"
```

Consequently, the `s/staging/development/g` substitution is never made.

#### Making xargs and shell work together in proper order

There is a fix for this:

```
$ echo "redis::staging::key" | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo RENAME {} $(echo {} | sed 's/staging/development/g')'
RENAME redis::staging::key redis::development::key
```

The above puts the bash commands within single-quotes and passes them as arguments to `sh`.  This way, the string is not processed by the shell until after xargs has made the substitutions.

Comment: Thank you. However, the correct output will need to be:
`RENAME redis::staging::key redis::development::key` (All as one line)

How would you tell sed to strip the new like from the "p" option?

Comment: Or is there a different technique to cause the shell to evaluate that variable in sed after the command runs?

Comment: @Excalibur See revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the cool sed-fu tricks! The & & and /2 were very useful here. My final command ended up being `redis-cli -n 5 KEYS "*::development""*" |xargs -I {} | sed 's/.*/RENAME & &/; s/development/staging/2'` Thank you!